# Wpf checkbox colorize

Tags: c#, wpf

How to colorize system checkbox in WPF?
Sample image:[Color checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnVU0.jpg)

I want a simple colorize a background and not effect and restyle checkbox.
But set `Background="Red"` change circle checkbox.
Ex.:[circle bg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU5Jr.png)
Thanks.

Comment: using `Background="#22FF0000"` gives basically the same look as the screenshot you have. What do you mean by *not effect and restyle checkbox*? What is the "circle checkbox"?

Comment: Thank you answer.
This example checkbox show in Windows Live Mail 2012 (Calendar)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the live visual tree tool within a wpf app to find the name/key of the check area. You can then create a style based on the default checkbox style with a setter that targets the item and sets it colour.